# Bash script to install package if already not installed (From a directory with many packages) - Fedora 17

Tags: bash, fedora, scripting, yum, dnf

I have a directory full of rpms (And their dependencies). Currently I am executing `yum localinstall ./packages_directory/*.rpm` to install all packages in there. It automatically skips the ones already installed. However this is taking too long if all packages are already installed. I would like for it to go faster for installed packages. An alternative I thought is to check if each one of  those packages are already installed (With some other command perhaps). If they are not installed then I run a localinstall on them. Can someone help me write the script for that? Or maybe a faster alternative.

Comment: run `createrepo` on the directory, then you can add a new repo to your yum.conf or whatever and do a yum install specifying just that repo.

Comment: Do not use Fedora 17. It is years EOL and unsupported. Update to current Fedora 23.

Comment: @Jakuje It is not an option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a script for it (Fedora 17). Assuming that the current directory where script is running is also the directory of where the rpms are located:

```
install_packages(){
    echo "Installing/Checking Fedora packages. Process may take a while..."
    for i in *
    do
        if test -f "$i" #Test if it is a file
        then
           i=$(basename $i) #Remove parent directory part of the string
           PACKAGE_NAME=${i::-4} #Remove .rpm from the end of file name
           if rpm -q $PACKAGE_NAME | grep "not installed" > /dev/null #If package not yet installed
           then
            echo "Installing $i ..."
                yum localinstall ./fc17/"$i" -y > /dev/null #Install this package 
           fi
        fi
    done    
    echo "Packages checked/installed"


}
```

For fedora 22 just replace `yum localinstall` with `dnf install`

Comment: You can make this go significantly faster by adding `--nosignature --nodigest` to your `rpm -q` call.

Comment: Also, your filename munging to get package name will work with all official Fedora packages, but third-party vendor packages may make the filename differ from the package name. So you could replace that with `rpm --nosignature --nodigest -qp --qf '%{name}-%{version}-%{release}.%{arch}\n' packagename.rpm`